# When subsetting to remove rows only removes one column values

Tags: r, rows, subset

I have data that looks something like this:

```
name   age   profit
Ann     -3     10
Ann     -2      5
Ann     1       23
Ann     2       15
Josh    -2      12
Josh    -1      34
Josh     0      1
Josh     1      21
Josh     2      26
```

I want to remove those rows for which `age` is negative.
After using

```
subset(profitData,age>0,select=c(name,age,profit))
```

I get this:

```
name   age   profit
Ann     1      10
Ann     2       5
Ann     3      23
Ann     4      15
Josh    1      12
Josh    2      34
Josh    3       1
Josh    4      21
Josh    5      26
```

So, only the values from the age column are removed but not the entire row.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How about `profitData[profitData$age>=0,]`?

Comment: Looks strange. You should (as always) post the output of `dput(profitData)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this will be OK:

```
profitData[profitData$age>0,]
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific subset question...

There's something hinky going on.  I run your code and get your desired output.  Start a clean session maybe:

```
profitData <- read.table(text="name   age   profit
Ann     -3     10
Ann     -2      5
Ann     1       23
Ann     2       15
Josh    -2      12
Josh    -1      34
Josh     0      1
Josh     1      21
Josh     2      26", header=T)

subset(profitData,age>0,select=c(name,age,profit))

## > subset(profitData,age>0,select=c(name,age,profit))
##   name age profit
## 3  Ann   1     23
## 4  Ann   2     15
## 8 Josh   1     21
## 9 Josh   2     26
```

Comment: request is for not negative, is 0 negative?

Comment: The request really isn't about how to subset, the poster seems to understand that.  It's more why what they expect with subsetting doesn't work.  The problem isn't 0 for the poster, that's a simple act of replacing ` > 0` with `< 0`; the poster is concerned that the values stated are replaced rather than subset.